# vmware for ubuntu 14.10

Tags: vmware

I have installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my laptop and want to install the vmware client software on my laptop. I cannot find vmware for clients in ubuntu software center, is there another way to installthis?

Answer (score 1):

VM Ware is a 3rd party application. And they do not provide a debian installer to be included into our software center. Instead they create a binairy bundle to install it.

So...

- Visit this link

  Pick the latest version in the dropdown box. That would be 6.0.4.
- Download the correct version for your system. I would expect it to be "VMware Player for Linux 64-bit". Details of the file:

  ```
  FILE NAME VMware-Player-6.0.4-2249910.x86_64.bundle
  BUILD NUMBER 2249910
  RELEASE DATE 2014-10-30
  CHECKSUMS
  MD5SUM: d047a2ff96e8150c4c947cb7b3e4cec8
  SHA1SUM: 8a470d44ed163ebafe2f9614e193e35138aef328
  ```
- While downloading: this software has some dependencies. You can install them with:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
  ```
- When the download is done make the file executable and execute it.

  ```
  chmod +x VMware-Player-6.0.4-2249910.x86_64.bundle
  sudo ./VMware-Player-6.0.4-2249910.x86_64.bundle
  ```

  (if you download the 32 version change the file name).
- It will start a graphical installation:

[image]

---

After this I quit the installation. On my work system I have 12.04 with 4.0.4 version and used this [OMG Ubuntu article](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-install-vmware-player-in-ubuntu.html) to install it (I needed to do that with the patch). That patch might be needed for 14.10+6.0.4 too and it might not work for 14.10. Ask another question regarding that if it does ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can freely download the vmplayer from vmware.com.  Use the latest version, but while I know it works on 14.04, I'm not sure it works on 14.10.  You will need the build-essentials package so the vmplayer module compile will work,